# GPO - Mapped drive for non-domain user on a domain computer

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-xp, group-policy

I am trying to add a mapped drive for a number of CNC machines that all run off Windows XP boxes that are joined to our domain, the computer policies apply fine but as the software for the CNC only runs on the local admin user account I can't get user GPOs to apply.

I have tried everything including Loopback mode in both Merge and Replace modes to see if either would somehow map the drive for the local admin user but no luck.

Is there any way (other than `net use` in a logon script - don't want to do this as is messy and hard to maintain) to map a network drive using GPO for local users?

(Or even ALL users on that computer OU would be perfect)

Comment: You are pretty much going against what GPO is meant to do. You would do better with setting up a local policy and duplicating it for the other machines.

Comment: Technet info to go with DanBig's answer. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/7cdc6ea4-4dd7-4be5-8ade-3ecdd76f4071/apply-gpo-loopback-to-local-users?forum=winserverGP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to mess with the domain GPO for local users (which will never work), setup a local security policy with the items you want, then duplicate it to the other computers.